# Change CSS background with JavaScript if the number in the class is above 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some sort of notification system. Currently displaying like "Messages: 0"
Around the "0" there's a box made with CSS.

I'd like to change the background of the CSS box with JavaScript if the number is above 0.

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it is entirely unclear what you're asking. Please update your question to contain a complete, self-contained example that fully illustrates the problem at hand.

Comment: As a reference, read the [ask] page to help you formulate a better question and be on your way to obtaining great answers. Welcome to SO, btw!

Comment: I felt like his question was pretty clear. Why the flag? Is it due to lack of code examples?

Comment: IMHO, I don't think it meets the mcve [ http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ] requirements but I did not downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<span class="number">0</span>
<span class="number">10</span>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".number").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().trim() != "0"){
        $(this).addClass("not-zero");
    }}
);
```

Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/94ga9d01/2/